# Can't upload zip files using ruby on rails and paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, zip, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm working on a rails web application. Just created and prepared some models and stuff. The application is very simple. But now I have a problem by setting up the gem paperclip to add attachments to a model. Almost everything works fine, like attaching images/jpg or even pdf.

But I can't upload zip files. I tried different zip files, but I'm always getting:
"Attachment Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError"

This is my model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attachment, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => ["application/pdf", "application/zip", "application/x-zip", "application/x-zip-compressed","application/octet-stream","image/jpg","image/png"]
  belongs_to :client
  has_one :status
end
```

I'm developing on a Mac (Yosemite), installed imagemagick via brew and using SQLite.

I added this to my Gemfile:

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'cocaine', '~> 0.5.4'
```

I did research on google the last hours, and there are many people struggling with paperclip, but I didn't find anybody with problems uploading zip files.

Maybe someone can help here.
Thanks

Comment: I just found out that I can upload zip files when I remove the line with "content_type..." and add stuff like "...:matches => [/zip\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ImageMagick can't read .zip files. See the acceptable file types here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

If you're trying to generate a thumbnail from a zip file ImageMagick should fail every time.

Try adding this to your model:

```
before_post_process :skip_for_zip

def skip_for_zip
   ! %w(application/zip application/x-zip).include?(asset_content_type)
end
```

Then your app won't try to process zip files as images

Comment: note: Your attribute is "attachment" so replace "asset_content_type" by "attachment_content_type".