# Paperclip and Zip - My .zip file is magically transforming into a .png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm having a problem with Paperclip. Easily enough, I am trying to get a .zip folder uploading using Paperclip - I've read around and it seems like it can be done.

However, my .zip uploads transform into the default 'missing.png' file - and I have no earthly idea why. The file is, er... well, the process is going through and I am not getting any errors, but obviously something is not turning out right.

I've followed the instructions of [Can't upload zip files using ruby on rails and paperclip gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049504/cant-upload-zip-files-using-ruby-on-rails-and-paperclip-gem) but it's still not... changing anything.

From what I can tell through a rails console run of the model in question, the file isn't uploading at all. The problem is, I'm not sure where or how or why.

Here's my book model

```
book.rb

    has_attached_file :content
    validates_attachment_content_type :content, :content_type => ["application/zip, application/x-zip"]

    before_post_process :skip_for_zip

def skip_for_zip
   ! %w(application/zip application/x-zip).include?(attachment_content_type)
end

end
```

And a quick rails console peek

```
2.1.6 :001 > Book.all
  Book Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Book id: 3, title: "Test", summary: "La la la", rating: nil, author_id: nil, word_count: nil, created_at: "2016-10-28 03:53:22", updated_at: "2016-10-28 03:53:22", cover_file_name: nil, cover_content_type: nil, cover_file_size: nil, cover_updated_at: nil, content_file_name: nil, content_content_type: nil, content_file_size: nil, content_updated_at: nil>, #<Book id: 4, title: "ugh", summary: "", rating: nil, author_id: nil, word_count: nil, created_at: "2016-10-28 03:59:33", updated_at: "2016-10-28 03:59:33", cover_file_name: nil, cover_content_type: nil, cover_file_size: nil, cover_updated_at: nil, content_file_name: nil, content_content_type: nil, content_file_size: nil, content_updated_at: nil>]> 
2.1.6 :002 >
```

Ignore the 'cover' section, there was a separate Paperclip attachment that I hid to diagnose the 'content' problem.

But note, I'm not getting ANY errors. At all. Whatsoever. So. Any help from the StackOverflow Rails Gawds would be greatly appreciated for a newb like me.

Comment: Can you please write you paperclip & paperclip gem version!! and check this property of your attachment. self.content.content_type inside any active record callbacks..

Comment: Could you include any code related to assigning the content - e.g., form declaration and controller action and set_params method. Have you checked if book.valid? or looked at book.errors? after attempting to save

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

As @henners66 suggested, I was completely missing the :content as a permitted param on my books controller - further, turns out I was declaring the 'valid content types' incorrectly. It should have been:

```
book.rb

    has_attached_file :content
    validates_attachment_content_type :content, :content_type => ["application/zip", "application/x-zip"]

    before_post_process :skip_for_zip

def skip_for_zip
   ! %w(application/zip application/x-zip).include?(attachment_content_type)
end

end
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I also had to add `"application/x-zip-compressed"` to the above